# Why my python visuals shows slower in Power BI service compared to that in Power BI desktop?

Tags: python, powerbi

I made a python visual in Power BI. The codes are shown below. It runs quite fast in Power BI desktop, the visual pops up in 1-2 seconds. However, when I publish it to the Power BI service, it takes 10 seconds to show this python visual. Why is this?

```py
dates_filtered = dataset.delivery_begin.unique()[-3:]
dataset_plot = dataset[dataset.delivery_begin.isin(dates_filtered)]
fig, ax = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()
if len(dates_filtered) == 3:
    colors = {
    dates_filtered[0] : "#92bbea" ,
    dates_filtered[1] : "#ea9d9a",
    dates_filtered[2] : "#85ceb3"}
elif len(dates_filtered) == 2: 
    colors = {
    dates_filtered[0] : "#ea9d9a",
    dates_filtered[1] : "#85ceb3"}
else:
    colors = {dates_filtered[0] :  "#85ceb3"}   

grouped = dataset_plot.groupby('delivery_begin')
for key, group in grouped:
    group.plot(ax=ax, kind='line', x = "ep_based_cumsum_bins", y = "adjusted_energy_price", label=key, c= colors[key], legend=False, linewidth = 4)
# grouped.apply(lambda x: x.plot(ax=ax, kind='line', x = "ep_based_cumsum_bins", y = "adjusted_energy_price", label=x.name, c= colors[x.name], legend=False, linewidth = 4))
for item in [fig, ax]:
    item.patch.set_visible(False)
ax.axis('off') 
# ax.legend(dataset_plot.delivery_begin.unique(), loc = 'upper left')
legend = matplotlib.pyplot.legend(fontsize=22, loc = 'upper left', frameon = False)
matplotlib.pyplot.setp(legend.get_texts(), color = 'none')
# ax.legend(loc='upper left', fancybox=True, framealpha=0)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Comment: I can't answer it fully, but if I were you I would investigated where the Power BI service executes Python code. It is never done by PowerBI self and it relies on an external engine to run the code. My guess is that it is a bit slower in communication than on your own machine.